# cannot find modules/impl: Permission denied collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c, gcc, module, compiler-errors

I have a project in C and I'm trying to modularize some functions. However, when I run the command to compile it returns this error.

```
PS C:\Users\muril\OneDrive\Desktop\projeto-sgbd-master> gcc main.c modules/impl* -I modules/includes
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find modules/impl: Permission denied collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

File structers

```
|---project/
|---main.c
|---modules/
|   |---include/
|       |---module1.h
|       |---modele2.h
|   |---impl/
|       |---modele1.c
|       |---modele2.c
```

Why this error occurs?

Comment: Make it `modules/impl/*` instead. Right now you are trying to compile the actual directory named `impl`

Comment: Thank you so much. Now the program can compile!

Comment: Lovely! You're welcome!